# Azure function app in Intellij Community Edition Failed to validate function runtime: Cannot run program "java": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, azure, intellij-idea, azure-functions

I'm running Linux Manjaro and I'm writing my first Azure Function App in Java. I have succeeded in deploying from Intellij the function app but when trying to run it locally I get this error

[image: Error image]

I have tried to add java to the PATH variable and setting the JAVA_HOME variable as well but nothing fixes my issue.

I am also using the Zulu java 11 runtime in case it's relevant.

Comment: I have installed Visual Studio Code and it works there.

Comment: Please check whether the latest [Function Core Tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools) is installed. If it still doesn't work after installation, please try to reinstall the `Azure Toolkit` plugin.

Comment: You can also use `java -version` to verify that the Java path is configured correctly.

Comment: I have installed both, from the terminal both java and func work.

Comment: Can this solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up your `SDK` here may solve your problem:

[image]

Comment: No idea why but making sure I use java 1.8 worked, thanks!